Environment variables passed with docker run -e not working as expected
Why is the following not printing "1"?
docker run --rm -e ONE='1' alpine echo $ONE


Because it's being resolved before it's passed to docker run?

Also see for example echo environment variable with docker run.

This question is similar to: echo environment variable with docker run. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue is that $ONE is expanded by your host shell before being passed to Docker. To fix this, you need to execute the command inside the container's shell, like this:
docker run --rm -e ONE='1' alpine sh -c 'echo $ONE'

This ensures $ONE is interpreted inside the container, and the output will correctly be 1
